# IACore.dll, IAWinFX.dll, IALoader missing

Tags: c#, windows, handwriting

I have installed the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4 through this link ( http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/dlx/en-us/listdetailsview.aspx?FamilyID=6b6c21d2-2006-4afa-9702-529fa782d63b ) on a Windows 7 machine and trying to following the instructions about how to create a Handwriting Recognition WPF application using this guide ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754080%28VS.90%29.aspx ).

However, I couldn't find the IACore.dll, IAWinFX.dll and IALoader.dll mentioned inside the guide. I have even done a search in my Windows installation drive just in case they are installed in another location. But it just seems that the files are not even installed anywhere.

Or is there any alternative for me to build a WPF Handwriting Recognition application?

Answer (score -1):

I found it in:

c:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Tablet PC\v1.7\

Comment: Not helpful. As the OP has suggested, either the installer refuses to install the libraries on some machines for some unknown reason or it's just not included. (it doesn't install the dlls with either the Win7 .Net 3.5 or the 4.0 SDK on my machine)

Comment: M.Stramm is right.  While the Tablet PC SDK installs without error, it doesn't include the Reference Assemblies on Windows 7, 8, or 10.  It only works on XP.  However, I have provided a solution that will work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502373/wpf-handwriting-net-4-5-windows-8-missing-iawinfx-dll-and-others/30516175#30516175